# Baryon effective Lagrangian

Tags: effective-field-theory, baryons

I'm trying to understand how to construct effective lagrangians for the hadrons. I understand the procedure for the mesons but I get stuck on baryons. In particular I don't understand how the baryons should transform under a chiral transformation. I mean for the mesons it was easy because they could be interpreted as the Goldston bosons of the theory, but for baryons?

For example in the $SU(3)_L\times SU(3)_R$ chiral model the only thing I know about the baryons octect $B$ is that it must transforms as the eight dimensional representation of the unbroken symmetry $SU(3)_V$  but I don't get why, under $SU(3)_L\times SU(3)_R$, it should transform like
$$
B\to h(\phi,g)Bh^{\dagger}(\phi,g)
$$
where $\phi$ are Goldstone bosons fields, $g$ is a $SU(3)_L\times SU(3)_R$ transformations and $h$ is a $SU(3)_V$ transformation as claimed for example in Pich, A. & de Rafael, E., 1991. Strong CP violation in an effective chiral Lagrangian approach. Nucl. Phys., B367(2), pp.313–333.